# opencensus exporter - one global or per thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grpc, stackdriver, opencensus

I am using Opencensus to do some monitoring on a grpc server with 10 workers. My question is whether, when making a Tracer, the exporter for the tracer should be local or Global. IE

this is the server:

server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))

Do I do:

tracer_module.Tracer(sampler=always_on.AlwaysOnSampler(), exporter=GLOBAL_EXPORTER)
where:
GLOBAL_EXPORTER = stackdriver_exporter.StackdriverExporter(transport=BackgroundThreadTransport))
OR do I do:
tracer_module.Tracer(sampler=always_on.AlwaysOnSampler(), exporter=stackdriver_exporter.StackdriverExporter(transport=BackgroundThreadTransport)))

I have tried both and they work. The former will use a global exporter which should be more efficient (I would think) but the aggregation seems a bit odd (one call is 'aggregated with another). On the other hand, the second way makes a second exporter (which is short lived, since it will exist only for that call) and does seem to export correctly. Question is more what is more correct from a system perspective. IE for the second option does creating stackdriver_exporter.StackdriverExporter(transport=BackgroundThreadTransport) invalidate a different exporter (which was created in a different thread)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a global exporter.  It was not intended for a new export thread to be created for every Tracer.  There should be one background thread running which handles all exporting to StackDriver.

As for the aggregation, it shouldn't be aggregating all the spans together.  That may be a bug in the StackDriver UI (there are a number of known issues).